# AJAX not working in JQUERY confirm dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call an ajax function after the user confirms a [JQUERY confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) dialogue. But after putting in the confirm part. It gives me an error and doesn't work. Please note that the ajax function works fine when placed outside the confirm dialogue.

My code is

```
 function approveApp(intAppId) {      
         $.confirm({
             title: 'Are you sure you want to approve this application?',
             content: '',
             buttons: {
                 confirm: function () {
                     var test = intAppId;
                     alert(test) //This alerts the word 'Undefined'
                     var intAppId = intAppId;
                     $.ajax({
                         url: 'adminreport.aspx/approveApp',
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: JSON.stringify({ intAppId: intAppId }),
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json",

                         success: function (data) {
                             if (data.d) {
                                 alert("It worked!");
                             }
                         }
                     });
                 },
                 cancel: function () {

                 }
                 }
             }
         });

     }
```

Comment: What on earth is `$.confirm()`? That is not part of jquery and is not built into browsers. Also, show your error.

Comment: alert(test) //This alerts the word 'Undefined' - this looks like you call approveApp with undefined. can you show code that calls approveApp

Comment: @GeorgeMauer While OP didn't exactly phrase it in such a way that would indicate such, "jQuery Confirm" is the name of a popular plugin: https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Comment: is your function argument defined in first place?

Comment: You declare `var intAppId` in the `confirm` function. This overrides the `intAppId` of the outer scope.

Comment: `if (data.d) `  is not need to read data as json and after do that?
ParsJson

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @GeorgeMauer haha ... Read this https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/   Pretty neat I must say

Comment: @PeterMader Yep That seemed to be the problem. I was doing that to hold the outer parameter. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Santi Yes of course i will, but i still have to wait 4 minutes before accepting it...StackOverFlow rules

Comment: @JasonKrs I figured it was some random thing from the internet. Just wanted to give direction to actually list what library he's assuming. We need to train newcomers to SO to ask questions properly

Comment: @JasonKrs, i would've listed the library i'm using if it was the reason of my error. But since it's not..listing it will only confuse and waste other user's time by figuring out whether the error is from it or not.

Comment: @SinanNourEddine Have you any idea of how broad the knowledge is at stackoverflow ? The only way you can confuse people here is if your question lacks proper details. I would not be surprised if the creator of that plugin would look at your question if you'd added it.... Stackoverflow is a very diverse community and some people here are really really really smart mate. Don't underestimate that fact and ask questions with enough details... There is a reason why GeorgeMauer asked you for that plugin name... Please read or at least skim through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the parameter to the outer function as `intAppId`.

However, you're also declaring that variable in the inner function and using it to (presumably) hold the outer parameter:

```
var intAppId = intAppId;
```

This re-declaration is hiding the outer variable.  You can just remove it entirely and just use the parameter in your ajax call.